# How to read Audio queue service bufer by byte?

Tags: objective-c, ios, audioqueueservices

I am recording sound from mic input using Audio queue service.

```
-(void)startRecording{

    [self setupAudioFormat:&recordState.dataFormat];

    recordState.currentPacket = 0;

    OSStatus status;
    status = AudioQueueNewInput(&recordState.dataFormat,
                                AudioInputCallback,
                                &recordState,
                                CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
                                kCFRunLoopCommonModes,
                                0,
                                &recordState.queue);
    if (status == 0)
    {
        // Prime recording buffers with empty data
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUFFERS; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"buf in");
            AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(recordState.queue, 16000, &recordState.buffers[i]);
            AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer (recordState.queue, recordState.buffers[i], 0, NULL);
        }


        status = AudioFileCreateWithURL(fileURL,
                                        kAudioFileAIFFType,
                                        &recordState.dataFormat,
                                        kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                                        &recordState.audioFile);

        if (status == 0)
        {
            recordState.recording = true;
            status = AudioQueueStart(recordState.queue, NULL);
            if (status == 0)
            {

                NSLog(@"Recording");

            }
        }
    }

    if (status != 0)
    {
        //[self stopRecording];
        NSLog(@"recording failed");
    }

}
```

on callback:

```
void AudioInputCallback(void * inUserData,
                        AudioQueueRef inAQ,
                        AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer,
                        const AudioTimeStamp * inStartTime,
                        UInt32 inNumberPacketDescriptions,
                        const AudioStreamPacketDescription * inPacketDescs)
{
    RecordState * recordState = (RecordState*)inUserData;
    if (!recordState->recording)
    {
        printf("Not recording, returning\n");
    }

    // if (inNumberPacketDescriptions == 0 && recordState->dataFormat.mBytesPerPacket != 0)
    // {
    //     inNumberPacketDescriptions = inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize / recordState->dataFormat.mBytesPerPacket;
    // }
    /*
    int sampleCount = recordState->buffers[0]->mAudioDataBytesCapacity / sizeof (AUDIO_DATA_TYPE_FORMAT);
    NSLog(@"sample count = %i",sampleCount);
    AUDIO_DATA_TYPE_FORMAT *p = (AUDIO_DATA_TYPE_FORMAT*)recordState->buffers[0]->mAudioData;
    for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++) {

        if (p[i] > 1000) {
            NSLog(@"%hd",p[i]);
        }

    }*/

    printf("Writing buffer %lld\n", recordState->currentPacket);
    OSStatus status = AudioFileWritePackets(recordState->audioFile,
                                            false,
                                            inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize,
                                            inPacketDescs,
                                            recordState->currentPacket,
                                            &inNumberPacketDescriptions,
                                            inBuffer->mAudioData);
    if (status == 0)
    {
        recordState->buffers[0] = nil;
        recordState->currentPacket += inNumberPacketDescriptions;
    }

    AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(recordState->queue, inBuffer, 0, NULL);
}
```

Here i want to read recorded buffer. is it possible to get something like this:

short[] buffer = ?;//here should an audio buffer converted to some structure (short[] just for example)

then i would like to read every element of this structure:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfBuffer; i++) {

            bufferVal = buffer[i];
}
```

In short how to handle buffer when recording ?

Thanks.